# Almost regular complex polytopes

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, polyhedra, polytopes

Within his 2nd edition of "Regular Complex Polytopes" Coxeter seems to have added a section about "Almost Regular Polytopes". I for one do not have access to that book, all I can access is its rewrite within [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_polytope#Other_complex_polytopes_with_unitary_reflections_of_period_two). (According to the latter, it even seems to be addressed within Coxeter's "Groups generated by Unitary Reflections of Period Two" too.) - However, I have to admit that I don't get it from that open access rewrite.

Thus my question is, whether someone could introduce me to their definition, about their groups, but most especially about their complex geometric realizations, i.e. their various elements, incidences, etc.

Allthough on wikipedia several ones are given together with their equivalences with other (simpler) complex polytopes, I currently am not able to dechiffer these there provided trigonal CDs with "internal" number. Esp. when it comes to the point what those graphics would tell on their respective polytopal elements.

--- rk

Comment: If you go online to "bookfinder" you can find two used copies of the 2nd edition of Coxeter's book in excellent condition for sale by reputable sellers at prices that do not seem completely outrageous.

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, as already mentioned within [operants on complex polytopes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691068/operants-on-complex-polytopes), that Shephard himself described them (somewhat differently from Coxeter, esp. wrt. the given number included into that triangular Coxeter-Dynkin diagram, possibly with legs) within his paper [UNITARY GROUPS GENERATED BY REFLECTIONS](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/87435E86E2FD055060686DD3FBB3C254/S0008414X00044060a.pdf/unitary_groups_generated_by_reflections.pdf). These after all thus seem to be just snubs of the regular complex polytopes.

--- rk